# In-game web browser asset for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Is there any sort of ready made asset for Unity to implement an in-game web browser? If not, what would be the easiest way to implement such a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the htmlTexture plugin:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity3d-plugin-for-embedding-webpages-on-windows-is-ready.83071/
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/htmltexture-plugin.4990/

You can download it from here: [htmlTexture Plugin](http://robterrell.com/htmlTexture.app.zip)

Comment: Thanks! Will this work on any platform? Also, the last link seems to be dead.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the link. Fixed it. It's quite an old piece of code, but it should be usable on any platform. Alternatively, take a look at [Awesomium](https://github.com/schlunsen/UnityAwesomium/blob/master/UnityAwesomiumSource/Unity/Unity/WebCore.h) for IE support.